# ZF2 v2.2.5. standard validation messages

Tags: php, zend-framework2

According to the Zend Framework 2 manual you have to use this code:

```
// Module.php

public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    //$this->bootstrapSession($e);
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');

    $translator = new \Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator();
    $translator->addTranslationFile(
        'phpArray',
        'vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/es/Zend_Validate.php',
        'default',
        'es_ES'
    );

    \Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
}
```

to translate the standard validation error messages but in my case it's not working.

Anybody know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Please define "not working".

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to say that I have solved the problem. I made some changes and my code looks like this right now:

```
\Locale::setDefault('es_ES'); //<- this line is new
$translator = new \Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator();
$translator->addTranslationFile(
    'phpArray',
    'lang/es/Zend_Validate.php',
    'default',
    'es_ES'
);
\Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
```

However the translation didn't work because the Zend_Validate.php provided by Zend Framework (vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/es/Zend_Validate.php in my case for Spanish) is obsolet and I had to change the error messages.

i.e.  for the EmailAddress validator class

I changed this:

"Invalid type given, value should be a string" =>

To this

"Invalid type given. String expected" =>

Because the static variable of EmailAddress class is:

self::INVALID => "Invalid type given. String expected",

and not

self::INVALID => "Invalid type given, value should be a string",